# Copy a file into a specific subfolder

Tags: batch-file, windows-11

```
"Here I am"-folder
  |
  |--- mainfolder 1
  |          |
  |          |--- subfolder 1
  |          |--- subfolder 2
  |
  |--- mainfolder 2
  |          |
  |          |--- subfolder 1
  |          |--- subfolder 2
```

I want to place a batch-file into the "Here I am"-folder and execute it from there. It should copy a file named *text.txt* into all the subfolder 2 only.

Tried:

```
@echo off 
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
cls 
set currentDirectory=%CD% 
FOR /D %%g IN ("*") DO ( 
   Pushd %CD%\%%g 
   FOR /D %%f IN ("*\Feedback Attachment(s)") DO ( 
      copy "%currentDirectory%\MarkSheet_Practical_4.xlsx" "%%~ff" 
   ) 
   Popd 
) 
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (simpler) approach:

```
@echo off

FOR /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%f IN (`DIR /s /b "subfolder 2"`) DO (
    ECHO Copying text.txt from . to "%%f"
    COPY test.txt "%%f"
)
```

More help:

- `FOR /?` which explain the use off FOR.
- `tokens=*` puts the complete return path from `DIR` into 1 variable (which is needed because of the space in the filename)

output:

```
D:\TEMP>HereIambatchfile.bat
Copying text.txt from . to "D:\TEMP\mainfolder 1\subfolder 2"
        1 file(s) copied.
Copying text.txt from . to "D:\TEMP\mainfolder 2\subfolder 2"
        1 file(s) copied.

D:\TEMP>
```

Answer (score 1):

That file copying task can be done with a batch file with the single command line:

```
@for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0subfolder 2" /AD /B /S 2^>nul') do @copy "%~dp0text.txt" "%%I\" >nul
```

**FOR /F** with a command line enclosed in `'` results in staring in background `cmd.exe` with option `/c` and the command line appended as additional arguments. So there is executed with Windows installed to `C:\Windows` in background:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Temp\Here I am\subfolder 2" /AD /B /S 2>nul
```

`%~dp0` references the drive and path of argument 0 of the batch file which is the batch file path which always ends with a backslash. In the example above is assumed that the batch file path is `C:\Temp\Here I am\`.

The command **DIR** searches

- in the specified directory `C:\Temp\Here I am`
- and in all subdirectories because of option `/S`
- for just directories because of option `/AD` (attribute directory)
- with the name `subfolder 2` in long or short name
- and outputs the names of the found directories in bare format because of option `/B` which means with just the directory name with full path because of option `/S`.

In case of no directory found with that name an error message is output by **DIR** to handle **STDERR** (standard error) which is redirected to device **NUL** to suppress it.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The output of **DIR** to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) of the background command process is captured by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and processed by **FOR** after started `cmd.exe` closed itself after finishing execution of **DIR**.

Empty lines are ignored always by **FOR** which do not occur here at all.

All other captured lines would be split up by default using normal space and horizontal tab as delimiters into substrings (tokens). This line splitting behavior is not wanted here. For that reason `delims=` is used to define an empty list of delimiters resulting in not doing the line splitting at all. The usage of `tokens=*` would work here too. It results in removing leading spaces/tabs from all lines and assigning the rest of the line to the specified loop variable. So `tokens=*` can be used also in this case because of all directory names output by **DIR** with full path have no leading spaces/tabs at all.

**FOR** would next look on first character of first substring (= fully qualified directory name) and would ignore the line on first character would be a semicolon which is the default end of line character. A fully qualified directory name starts with a drive letter or with a backslash in case of a UNC path. So the default `eol=;` can be kept here.

The directory name is assigned to the specified loop variable `I` and **FOR** runs the command **COPY** which copies the file `text.txt` in batch file directory into this directory with suppressing the success message output to handle **STDOUT** by redirecting it with `>nul` to device **NUL**.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains referencing batch file arguments with modifiers like `%~dp0`
- `copy /?`
- `dir /?`
- `for /?`

`@` at beginning of a command line results in suppressing the output of the command before execution. Both `@` can be omitted on batch file containing `@echo off` at top which turns off the command echo mode with suppressing the echo of this command too. The **FOR** command line is executed only once and so `@` is needed left to **FOR**, but the command **COPY** is executed multiple times and so `@` must be used also left to command **COPY** to suppress the output of it. This second `@` can be removed to get the **COPY** command output also into the console window to see the progress of the batch file.